# Upgrade react-admin v2 to v3, permissions is always empty and context is not consistent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I am stuck in a react-admin `v2` to `v3` upgrade with two weird issues while I was wrapping the `layout` like this:

```java
  composeLayout(Layout) {
    const ComponentLayout = ({ references, dispatch, ...props }) => ( // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      <WithPermissions
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        render={({ permissions }) => (
          <AppContextProvider
            permissions={permissions}
            references={references} 
          >
            <Layout {...props} />
          </AppContextProvider>
        )}
      />
    );

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      const references = {};
      Object.keys(state.admin.resources).forEach((name) => {
        set(references, `${camelizePath(name)}.name`, name);
      });
      return { references };
    };
    return connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentLayout);
  }
```

- `references` is correctly set but always empty object when reading it from the context afterward
- `permissions` is always `undefined`, while `authProvider.getPermissions()` always return a non empty array of permission.

This is the view within the debugger, it shows passed values to `AppContextProvider`, we see that `permissions` is `undefined` and `references` not empty:

[image]

This screenshot show what's in the context when we try to read from it, we can see that `references` is now an empty object:

[image]
It was working fine in react-admin v2.

Our goal is to:

- use references from a references object instead of writing hard references everywhere in our app.
- create a `pages` object that depends on user's permissions for the app so we do not write hard links everywhere in the app.

What did change recently that could cause such strange behavior in v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue which was not related to react admin. I was using `useState` within the context I had created, preventing it from refreshing. removing the `useState` was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Read the below section in https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/UPGRADE.md

Note that direct access to the authProvider from the context is discouraged (and not documented). If you need to interact with the authProvider, use the new auth hooks:

useLogin
useLogout
useAuthenticated
useAuthState
usePermissions

Comment: Thanks for the Upgrade guide v3 but I have read it multiple times. I am not using `authProvider` at all (so not from the context). `WithPermissions` in `ra-core` is in charge of calling the `authProvider`. Perhaps you should read [this](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/auth/WithPermissions.tsx) and [this](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v2.6.4/docs/Authorization.md#restricting-access-to-content-in-custom-menu). That's an interesting fact that they have removed `WithPermissions` from their doc and haven't talk about it in the upgrade guide.